# What will HttpClient do if connection in pool closed

Tags: httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

HttpClient has special connection manager(ThreadSafeClientConnManager or PoolingClientConnectionManager or MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager) which can support multi thread. My understanding is these connection manager will create connection pool and try to reuse existing connection in subsequence request.

My question is, will the existing connection be dropped, like by network device?
and if the connection is dropped, what HttpClient will do, if it will affect next request?

I meet lots of similar issue in these days after deploy our application to Azure, as Azure always close my connection after a few time. I want to make sure if HttpClient can handle this failover correctly.